# Help understanding wiring for exhaust fan

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

I’m changing out an exhaust fan in my bathroom. It has two switches installed already for separate light and fan. Here is a picture of the fan wiring.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzWdv.jpg
[image]
I’m confused about, specifically the black to white.on the left is coming from the switch, the middle is to the light and the right is to the fan. I’m just curious if this wiring is correct. Everything works but it doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: Yes it is permitted, it is called switch loop, but the hot white should have been market with black tape.

Answer (score 1):

This is permitted but it looks like the black wire and the white wire from the switch are reversed. You've got switch loop. The black and white wires on the left are your neutral white tied to the fan and always hot black tied to the black wire going to the switch. The black and white wires next to those two go to the switch. The always hot black should be tied to the white wire going to the switch, not the black wire, and that white wire should be marked with black tape. That same white wire should be marked at the switch location to show it's always hot. The black wire from the fan, which is now your switched hot should be tied to the black wire going to the fan.

All these connections look like they are taped. You need to get some yellow wire nuts (USA) and connect these wires correctly.